# intel C++ コンパイラーでoperatorをdefault宣言するとコンパイル時にエラーになる。

Tags: c++

下記のようにoperator `=`をdefaultで宣言するとintel c++ compilerでコンパイル時にエラーメッセージが出るのですが、gccやclangでは問題なくコンパイルできるので、コンパイル時のオプションが足りていないのでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ**

```
icpc -std=c++17 sample.cpp
ld: /tmp/icpczIU0ix.o:(.rodata._ZTV6Entity[_ZTV6Entity]+0x10): undefined reference to `Entity::operator=(Entity const&)'
```

**ソースコード**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class Entity {
    public:
        Entity() = default;
        virtual Entity & operator = ( Entity const & )=default;
    public:
        int index;
};

Entity e1 = Entity();

int main() {
    std::cout << e1.index;
    return(0);
}
```

**環境**
Intel Compiler: icpc (ICC) 19.0.5.281 20190815
OS: Arch linux

**追記**
インテルのフォーラムの方に報告したところ、バグとしてアクセプトされました。
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/837004

Answer (score 4):

[P0135R1    Guaranteed copy elision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html)で

> - If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object. [ *Example*: `T x = T(T(T()));` calls the `T` default constructor to initialize `x`. ]

とされているため

```
Entity e1 = Entity();
```

ももちろん

```
Entity e1;
```

として扱われます。[C++17 Features Supported by Intel® C++ Compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c17-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler)によるとP0135R1にはVersion 19.0.1で対応済みとされているため、質問の状況はコンパイラーのバグかと。

Answer (score 3):

sayuriさん回答にある通り、Intel C++ Compiler側のバグが疑われますね。

一方で、非virtualなコピー代入演算子であれば Intel C++ Compiler(icc) 19.0.1 でも期待通り動作するようです。
https://godbolt.org/z/aCnsXa

C++では、コピー代入演算子は非virtualメンバ関数とすることが推奨されます。virtualメンバ関数とする強い理由があれば別ですが、質問中コードであれば明らかに非virtualをおすすめします。
[C.60: Make copy assignment non-`virtual`, take the parameter by `const&`, and return by non-`const&`](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c60-make-copy-assignment-non-virtual-take-the-parameter-by-const-and-return-by-non-const)